# Check if user liked post Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to check if user liked the post and dont let like it anymore. The problem is that with my code when one of the users likes the post, I cannot like it with another user. I don't know why.

Controller:

```
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    foreach($posts as $p){
        foreach ($p->like as $like){
            $like = Like::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        }
    }
```

Post.php:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function like()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

Like.php:

```
     public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
```

User.php:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function like(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

HTML

```
                @if($like)
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up liked pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @else
                    <a href="/like/{{$p->id}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up likeBtn pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                @endif
```

Comment: what actually are you trying to achieve with your code in controller. your $like variable seem it's being overwritten

Comment: I have "Likes" table witch belongs `user_id', 'post_id' and I want to check if 'user_id' exists in the same row as 'post_id' then do not let like the post.

Comment: you want to restrict user from liking the post if he/she has already liked the post. Right?

Comment: Yes, thats right! :D

Comment: then why this nested loop and all? Is there any specific purpose for using the loop. I mean you can simply done it by using the post_id & user_id.

Comment: Ok, You want to check for all existing post. Got it

Comment: @jonju hey maybe u can create a discussion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do the loop in controller. Do it in view(blade)

**Edited Controller**

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
$likes = Like::select('post_id')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
$likeArr=array_flatten($likes->toArray()); //convert multidimensional array to single array for easy access
return view('yourview',['posts'=>$posts,'likes'=>$likeArr]);
```

**VIEW**

```
@foreach($posts as $p)
    @if(in_array($p->id,$likes))
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up liked pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    @else
        <a href="/like/{{$p->id}}">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up likeBtn pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get this: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: Which line did you get this?

Comment: It doesnt show. But it writes: `at Grammar->columnize('post_id') in Grammar.php line 121`

Comment: It Works! :) Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that Auth user liked post or not, I did in this way.

Post.php

```
class Post extends Model{
   public function likes(){
      return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
   }
   public function isAuthUserLikedPost(){
      return $this->likes()->where('user_id',  auth()->id())->exists();
   }
}
```

Comment.php

```
class Comment extends Model{
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

And in your view you can use as:

```
{{ $post->isAuthUserLikedPost() ? 'do-something' : 'do-something else' }}
```